# Communicating & Resuming PTY processes

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to make a system where a program launches a PTY session using the ruby PTY library `PTY.spawn` and feeds in input and output with the input and output variables provided from the spawn method. The spawned process file itself reads from STDIN and writes to STDIN out so this approach effectively highjacks the input and output streams from the spawned file. This works great so far.

However I am also attempting to close the parent file and keep track of the pts file path (that the spawn command establishes when called) so that I can resume communicating with the PTY instance. So lets say that I have a pts file called `/dev/pts/17`, and I wish to resume communications with it, then I would simple create a file handle for input and output like so:

```
io_file = '/dev/pts/17'
output = File.open(io_file, "r")
input = File.open(io_file, "w")
```

The problem hits me when I try to read from the output file. Whenever I do `output.readline` the process hangs (blocks). I have no way of getting around this. Any idea what's going on? Is there another way to resume PTY instances?

Comment: If you meant [this `PTY` library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html), it looks like you are trying to set the read-only variables and (surprisingly) your `output` file indeed links to nowhere. AFAIK, there is no way to force `PTY` to use the `/dev/pts` of your choice.